# FTPClient login method replies 530 PASS command failed from the server

Tags: ftp, command, server, mainframe

```
 FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    try
    {
        client.connect(currentServerHostname);
        System.out.println("Connection is successful");
        System.out.println("Reply String: " + client.getReplyString());
        client.login(currentServerUser, currentServerPass);
        System.out.println("login ok");             
        System.out.println("Reply String: " + client.getReplyString());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("No connection was established");
    }
```

This code shows error like 530 Pass command failed in the line client.login() method.

Comment: 1) In your code, where does the 530 Pass command come in... you're not printing e (note that catching Exception is bad practice).. so is it coming from getReplyString() or did you over simplify the code
2) have you tried this with a standalone client to verify your username/password do work as expected?

Comment: 530 PASS command failed is the reply string from the host server. Yes, this comes from the client.getReplyString() method. Thanks for your advice. The host server is a IBM mainframe server.

Comment: Please try Googling "530 PASS" - I did and the documentation provides some pointers.  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.cs3cod0/ftp530-20.htm

Comment: I have surfed that @cschneid. Thanks for your help. I am able to login through commands. There is no way that user name and password mismatches.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say your user name and password are mismatched.  It says that "While validating the user ID and password or password phrase of the client, a function issued by the FTP server failed. See the previous 530 reply information for details."  So there should be another 530 reply prior to the 530 PASS that says what the real problem is.  The documentation also says, for the User Response (that's you in this case) "Contact the system programmer."  Talk to the mainframe support folks.  There may be more information in a log on the mainframe.

Comment: I have got answer for this @cshneid. The server that I tried to connect does not support FTPClient. I am using S3270 adapter for connecting it now. If anyone faces the same issue use S3270. Mail me cocsabarish@gmail.com if u have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to login with a user with a RACF account but that user (maybe) don't have an UID defined in the OMVS segment.

See if this helps:

**Problem(Abstract)**

An FTP client user attempts to log on to a z/OS FTP server. After the correct password is entered for user verification, the following server reply is received:

```
530 PASS command failed
```

**Diagnosing the problem**

With the ACC and FLO DEBUG options specified for the FTP server (see the section "Documentation for FTP Server Problems" in the Technote MustGather: Collect Troubleshooting Data for FTP for the z/OS Communications Server for instructions on starting an FTP server trace), the following messages are included in the FTP server trace:

```
RA0786 pass: use __passwd() to verify the user 
RA0809 pass: __passwd() failed - EDC5163I SAF/RACF extract error. (errno2=0x090C1C00) 
RA0888 pass: The username access has been revoked 
SR2910 reply: entered 
SR2947 reply: --> 530 PASS command failed
```

In v1r12 and later, the messages appear as:

```
RA0862 pass: use __passwd() to verify the user
RA1100 pass: getpwnam() failed - EDC5163I SAF/RACF extract error. (errno2=0B490808)
SR3360 reply: entered
SR3397 reply: --> 530 PASS command failed
```

Consider adding an ACCESSERRORMSGS TRUE statement to the FTP.DATA input used by the server (typically referenced via the SYSFTPD DD in the started proc). This will cause the server to provide more information to the end user about the nature of any logon failure (besides just '530 PASS command failed'). Some sites' security policies restrict providing more information in these cases, which is ACCESSERRORMSGS defaults to FALSE.

**Resolving the problem**

Each user logging in to the FTP server must have a UID defined in the user's OMVS segment. In this case, the user logging in does not have a UID defined in the OMVS segment, resulting in the PASS command failure. To resolve the problem, define a UID in the user's OMVS segment.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed analysis @bitfhacker. The server doen't support FTPClient. I am using s3270 Adapter for getting my things done. Thanks once again.